# Rails - Adding a Include/JOINs to a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my controller to obtain a project's team members:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@teammembers = @project.permissions.includes(:user).joins(:user, :role).select("*")
```

The problem here is that the user's table belongs_to the instance model. And the instance model has a name, which I want in @teammembers.

I tried adding this in like follows:

```
@teammembers = @project.permissions.includes(:user).joins(:user, :role, :instance).select("*")
```

but that errors with: "Association named 'instance' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Which kinda makes sense since Permissions includes (user_id, role_id, and project_id)

Suggestions on how I can join the instance table for instance.name in this query so my view doesn't hit the db so many times to look up the instance.name?

Thanks

Cleaned it up

Comment: I think it would be a bit clearer if you showed the models. Is it really as convoluted a design as your description makes it seem?

Comment: It would help to show how the "belongs_to" and "has_many" are defined in the models.

Comment: Did you guys get the info you needed? Just checking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.joins({:user, :instance}, :role)
```